# parser.BytesFeedParser().Close() return empty list in Python's email.parser

Tags: python, email

I'm trying to parse all emails from my mail-server.But when I try to process the data with using `close()` from Python's email.parser.BytesFeedParser,I get empty list error:

```
IndexError: pop from empty list
```

The code like belows:

```
client = poplib.POP3(host=theServer)
client.user(user=user)
client.pass_(pswd=password)

oriData = [client.retr(i)[1] for i in range(1, len(client.list()[1]) + 1)]

a = parser.BytesFeedParser()
for eleList in oriData:
    for ele in eleList:
        print(ele)
        a.feed(ele)
        print(a)
    test = a.close()
```

In the python's related [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/email.parser.html),it said:

> close()
> Complete the parsing of all previously fed data and return the
> root message object. It is undefined what happens if feed() is called
> after this method has been called.

That makes me confused.I construe it as when I apply the `close()`,it will return the `EmailMessage` object.I'm sure that the feeded data is not null but it finally return an empty list.I have searched this problem with many search-engines but get no answers so I push this question in stackoverflow. Can someone help me and explain why I make this mistake?

Comment: I'm now using library [zmail](https://github.com/zhangyunhao116/zmail) instead.But I'm still grad to see someone can solve my question.The problem mentioned in this post really make me stuck on last night.